# Expected value of repeating subsequences in permutations of a word

Tags: probability

I don't know how to solve the following problem, from *Understanding Probability* by Henk Tijms.

> What is the expected value of the number of times that two adjacent
>   letters are the same in a random permutation of the word Mississippi?

Mississippi contains 4 times the letters $I$ and $S$, two times the $P$ and one $M$.

To count the number of times that two adjacent letters are the same, I introduce the random variable
$$
X_i=\begin{cases}
1 \qquad&\text{if the letters }i\text{ and }i+1\text{ are the same} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, the requested value is:
$$
E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}E(X_i).
$$
The probability that the letters at place $i$ and $i+1$ are the same is difficult to compute for me, so I am not sure that this is the right approach.
I would start by computing
$$
P(X_i)=\frac{4}{11}\frac{3}{10}
$$
for the letters $I$ and $S$, but this does not count the fact that these two letters may have been used in other places of the word.

Edit: after the answer by @e-a, I can compute the correct probability for $X_i$:
$$
P(X_i) = \frac{4}{11}\frac{3}{10}+\frac{4}{11}\frac{3}{10}+\frac{2}{11}\frac{1}{10} = \frac{13}{55}.
$$
Then, the expectation value of $X_i$ is:
$$
E(X_i)=1\cdot P(X_i)=\frac{13}{55},
$$
and
$$
E(X)=10E(X_i)=\frac{130}{55}\simeq 2.364.
$$

Edit: here's the result of a few numerical simulations.

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{number of permutations} & E(X) \\
\hline 
10^2 & 2.45\\
10^3 & 2.37\\
10^4 & 2.363\\
10^5 & 2.35382 \\
10^6 & 2.363567\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is valid except (as you yourself noted) the probability.

The best way to compute that probability would be to do a little bit of partitioning (i.e. considering all the possibilities separately).

In particular, if letter $i$ and $i+1$ are the same, then letter $i$ is either i, s, or p.

P(letters $i$ and $i+1$ are the same) = P(letters $i$ and $i+1$ are the same and letter $i$ is i) + P(letters $i$ and $i+1$ are the same and letter $i$ is s) + P(letters $i$ and $i+1$ are the same and letter $i$ is p) = $\frac{4}{11} \frac{3}{10} + \frac{4}{11} \frac{3}{10} + \frac{2}{11} \frac{1}{10}$.

The beauty of using the indicator variable is that you do not have to consider where those letters may have been used elsewhere! Remember that expectation is linear even if your random variables are dependent. You can think of it as all of those locations behave as some "average location", even though they are dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added a complete answer to my original question, is it correct?

Comment: Looks valid! If you know how to program, you can also simulate it to verify it!

Comment: Done it, so we can be sure. Seems like the solution is good!